# How do you set an STM32F4 IRQ handler without using the HAL?

Tags: stm32, cortex-m4

I'm using the STM32F405xx/407xx architectures, which is a Cortex-M4.

The online documentation and tutorials on this subject are overwhelmingly HAL-based. I am converting a project over from another uC architecture and would like to know how to set my function as interrupt service routine, assign the IRQ a priority, and clear its associated interrupt mask bit so that it is ready to handle timer update interrupt events.

Do I just write an address into the vector table itself? Would I follow that with a `NVIC_SetPriority()` and `NVIC_EnableIRQ()` call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can edit the startup code assembly file. For example, startup_stm32f103xb.s has both a vector table "call site" and a symbol defined for TIM2_IRQHandler. That can be renamed to something else if you aren't using HAL to manage that timer peripheral.

Answer (score 4):

If you use the standard startup code, it defines the vector names. So you write a standard C function with the vector name and that will be the IRQ handler. The HAL just provides the handler for you if you use it.